# SQL correlated subquery of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have tables:

```
Person(SSN, name, address)
Car(license, year, model)
Accident(license, accident-date, driver, damage-amount)
Owns(SSN, license)
```

The question asks:

Find the license number of all cars that have been involved in more than one accident (DO NOT RETURN DUPLICATES).

One of the answers is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.license 
FROM Accident A1 
WHERE A1.license IN (SELECT A2.license 
                     FROM Accident A2 
                     WHERE A1.accident-date <> A2.accident-date)
```

It never checks that A1.license = A2.license in the correlated subquery. So to my understanding, the subquery checks if a tuple in A1 has a different accident date than a tuple in A2, even if the two tuple have different licenses. So shouldn't this be wrong?

EDIT: It is assumed that a car cannot have more than one accident in a day.

Comment: This "answer"  is plain wrong, it returns *all* rows if there's more than one date in `Accident`. As you already said there's `AND A1.license = A2.license` missing.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The question did not specify, but since my class is learning just mysql, I have tagged mysql.

Comment: The answer is incorrect, unless you make the assumption that a car cannot have two accidents on the same day.

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated that. It was assumed that a car cannot have more than once accident in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `IN` operator is checking for licenses equality. Lets make a test. Say `Accidents` table contains rows:

```
License  AccidentDate
L1       20151001
L1       20151020
L2       20151025
```

Correlated subquery is evaluated for each row of the outer query. Imagine a cursor that loops over the rows.

For `row1` `A.Licence` is `L1`. Inner subquery just checks for dates different from `20151001` and it will find `row2` and `row3(L1, L3)`. So `A.Licence` i.e. `L1` is in the resultset of inner subquery and it will be returned in final result. So do second row. But `row3` will not be included, because there are no `L2` in dates other then `20151025`. So the query is correct.

Comment: Why won't row 3 be returned from the subquery? Inside the subquery, we never check for A1.license = A2.license. So, the subquery would compare the date of row3 to the date of row1, and the dates are different, thus it will return, no?

Comment: No, subquery compares dates to date of outside query's current row. Where clause will eliminte all rows where IN predicate evaluates to false. Now imagine in outside query you are in position row3. L2 20151025. What about inner subquery? It serches for ros with dates other then outside date 20151025 and finds 20151001 and 20151020 but both are L1 so you get L2 IN(L1) when you are in position row3. So predicate is false and row3 is fiktered out.

Comment: To say it in words:  give me such rows from accidents where license number can be found in a set of license numbers with dates other then date of my crash. If I can find myself in a set with other date it means that car was in a crash multipl times.

Comment: Okay, let me try to comprehend this. The IN clause kind of plays the role of checking A1.license = A2.license. When we iterate down to A2.row3, we wanna compare the dates to rows in A1. But since L1 IN L2 is false, we do not check the rows with license L1.

Comment: OH. For each tuple in the outer query, we execute the inner query. I was under the impression that the subquery is executed entirely first and then outer query checks the result returned, but that is for non-correlated subqueries. Thank you! I understand now.